English Dystopian Film
I saw the last half an hour of this film on TV. The movie looks to have been made in the late 60's, early 70's. I think it was set in London. There had been some type of "Collapse". The streets were filled with garbage and there was graffiti everywhere. There was a scene where people were leaving the city, on foot with their belongings.
There was a house where older youths were looking after a group of young children. Teenage gangs were running wild in the streets. Some older people had stayed behind in their apartments trying to survive in the city.
The lead actress may have been Julie Christie but I'm not sure. This film was a character drama, quite slow, no real action as such.
Does anyone know the name of this film?

Brazil (1985) perhaps ?

Sounds like Memoirs of Survivors (1981) and it indeed has Julie Christie in it. The movie is based on Doris Lessing dystopian novel "Memoirs of Survivors", published in 1974. Takes place in near-future Britan.

That's the movie, the bit I saw was intriguing I will check it out. I am familiar with Brazil and Fahrenheit 451, both great films but not the ones I was after.
